# Get the last record with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get the last record, but I ger the first record.
What am I doing wrong?

My Table permission

```
|id|pid|uid|
| 1| 2 | 2 |
| 2| 5 | 2 |
```

My Table fruits

```
|id|pid|number1|number2|
|1 | 1 | 50    | 100   |
|2 | 1 | 10    | 100   |
|3 | 1 | 100   | 100   |    <== Try get last record
```

I want get the last record, but I can't.

I create the query, but not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fruits.pid), permission.pid, fruits.number1, fruits.number2 
FROM permission 
LEFT JOIN fruits ON permission.pid = fruits.pid 
WHERE permission.uid = '2' 
GROUP BY fruits.pid 
ORDER BY fruits.id DESC
```

I need the result:

```
|pid|pid|number1|number2|
|3  | 1 | 100   | 100   |
```

Comment: what's your criteria to pick the last record? biggest id or biggest number1 or what?

Comment: @ProGu biggest id

Comment: Why not just order by DESC and pick just top 1?

Comment: Why I need the last data.
DESC not work for get last data.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with DISTINCT?  It does not work like that

Comment: @ysth I just want a way to work.

Comment: `GROUP By` & `DISTINCT` are not required, `ORDER BY fruits.id DESC LIMIT 1` will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join doesn't join any rows. The value of `fruits.pid` is always 1. The values of `permissions.pid` are (2, 5). Thus, your join of `fruits.pid = permission.pid` doesn't find any rows that match, so you're not getting the results you expect. If you drop the `DISTINCT` in the query and remove the `GROUP BY` (which causes it to fail in MySQL 8) your query produces:

```
pid     pid number1 number2
null    2   null    null
null    5   null    null
```

The row you want isn't in the result set, so of course you don't get it.

The other problem you have is that the number 3 is not in the column `fruits.pid`. It's an `id` value, so I suspect you're joining on the wrong field. And you've got `permission.pid` as the second field returned by your query, but that column only contains 2 and 5, as noted earlier, but you want a value of 1 there; thus, it appears you want to return `fruits.pid` as the second column of the result set. So something like:

```
SELECT fruits.id, fruits.pid, fruits.number1, fruits.number2 
FROM fruits 
LEFT JOIN permission
  ON permission.id = fruits.pid 
WHERE permission.uid = '2' 
ORDER BY fruits.id DESC
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79cfa93aa09ffbf3d4eb5341b8d4fa01)